# where is the mysql database located?

Tags: mysql, grails

The datasource has the following connection string for the database

[image]

Now, i am trying to parse this url. It looks like the database is located in some external servers. I checked service list in this server and it didn't list mysql so i am very positive the url is pointing to an external server. The host name below is mysql. Does this mean the database could be in mysql.com? I want to connect to this database so that i can execute some sql queries. Is there a way to do that? Thanks for the help.

**Updated**

Thanks for the answer. I checked the ipaddress of the machine that has the grails app and also the ip address of mysql hostname using ping. They differ so i assume the mysql is a separate machine. Is that correct?

[image]

Comment: The database will be held locally, although I'm not sure how jdbc works. It's not hosted at mysql.com.

Comment: i thought if the database was there then wouldn't the host be localhost and also the fact that mysql is not running in this machine suggests to me that the database is somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this url, database is located on host named `mysql`. It has nothing to do with `mysql.com`. `mysql` may be a local machine or other server in the network.

For example check `ping mysql` from terminal on the server and it will show you IP of the server with mysql. By IP you can try to find which hardware this is.

If you want to connect to this server from your local computer, use the same connection string but `ping mysql` must point to the same server from your PC as from server. Or replace `mysql` in connection string to IP which server will show

Comment: As your Network Administrator. That is a internal server.  Also look at your "hosts" file.

Comment: yes, most probably (server may have more interfaces but you would see them as additional `ethX`) this is different machine and you should be able to connect to it using this IP which you see in PING. If you cannot connect, mysql privileges for user you use may be restricted to specific IP (for example of the server with Grails app)